# phpmyadmin not showing any icons?

Tags: mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin, vesta

Phpmyadmin now showing any icons,

I have vestaCP + nginx on the server. All the functionalities works normally but icons not visible. here is a pic. any help?

[image: phpmyadmin]

Comment: Check the developer console. It'll tell you why they're failing (404 etc.) - or try going to one of the icons via its URL directly.

Comment: @ceejayoz All the icons are mapped to xx.com/phpmyadmin/themes/dot.gif when i copy their adresses. What command should I run for the error? I am running centos

Comment: Use a web browser, such as Chrome, and look in the Developer Tools window for the Network requests for each resource. If you have to use a command-line approach, try `wget http://xx.com/phpmyadmin/themes/dot.gif`

Comment: Ok They are all looking like 404. Anybody know how to fix it? I have searched a lot on google but couldnt find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at the console, to see if there's a notification regarding cross origin resource sharing. If this isn't configured properly, no icons will be diplayed.